# Windowsデスクトップアプリケーションプログラムはデバッグの役に立ちますか？

Tags: windows

Windowsデスクトップアプリケーションプログラムを利用してみたいと考えています。
Windowsデスクトップアプリのエラーレポートが取得できるMicrosoftのサービスです。

私はバグの原因究明に非常に役に立つだろうと考えているのですが、上司は今ひとつ納得していないようで、導入コストに見合わないと考えているようです。（ここでいう導入コストとは社内で承認を得るための人件費などのこと）
上司を説得したいので、どのように役に立ったか、利用されたことのある方に伺いたいです。

以下公式サイトです。
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/appxpkg/windows-desktop-application-program#retrieve-analytic-data-using-the-microsoft-store-analytics-api

Comment: ちなみに前提条件は整っているのでしょうか？ 例えばコード署名が必要になるようですが、コード署名に対応した証明書はお持ちでしょうか？

Comment: 証明書を使用していますが、他チームの担当であるため詳細は把握していません。休み明けに問い合わせてみます。

Comment: 別方向から、エンドユーザーの現場で何か問題が発生した時に、情報収集から解決までにかかる平均的なコストとそうした問題の発生頻度を掛けて、導入/運用に掛かるコストと節約できると想定されるコストが見合うかどうかを比べてみる感じでしょうか。そもそも発生頻度や対処コストが低いとか既に何かの仕組みがあってある程度の対応が為されていれば追加で何かするハードルは高いでしょうし、それらが考えられていないなら検討中の仕組みに限らず何かを準備して組み込んでおく必要があるでしょう。

Comment: 証明書の管理が別チームなのかもしれませんが、コード署名の有無はご自身で分かるはずでは？ 分からないのだとしたらコード署名していない可能性が高くなります。

Comment: kunifさん
sayuriさん
ご回答ありがとうございます。

すみません。不勉強でコード署名の確認方法を知りませんでした。解説サイトを見つけたので週明けに確認します。
ちなみに、ウィンドウズデスクトップアプリケーションプログラムを使用された経験はありますか？
どのように運用されたのか伺いたいです。